# Error: The integer literal 9223372036854775807 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript

Tags: flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to build my flutter app and its throwing compilation error

**flutter build web --release --verbose**

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: /C:/flutter_windows_2.0.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/huawei_location-5.1.0+301/lib/location/location_request.dart:63:23:
           Error: The integer literal 9223372036854775807 can't be represented exactly in JavaScript.
               _expirationTime = 9223372036854775807;
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           Error: Compilation failed.
```

**this class only have this construtor** : ***/location/location_request.dart***

```
LocationRequest() {
    _priority = PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY;
    _interval = 3600000;
    _fastestInterval = (_interval ~/ _FASTEST_INTERVAL_FACTOR);
    _isFastestIntervalExplicitlySet = false;
    _expirationTime = 9223372036854775807;
    _numUpdates = 2147483647;
    _smallestDisplacement = 0.0;
    _maxWaitTime = 0;
    needAddress = false;
    language = '';
    countryCode = '';
  }
```

**i try this in my code to update to expirationTime to minor value, but i have the same error**

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest();
locationRequest.expirationTime = 1000000;
```

**Any idea how to fix this?**

Comment: You have `_expirationTime` in the first snippet, but `expirationTime` in the second. If that's really what you're doing, then does it stand to reason that the original error would remain?

Comment: locationRequest.expirationTime = 1000000;  this is a set method of the class location_request.dart

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following solution:

** In "location_request.dart" file

- Line 34: int -> BigInt
- Line 63: _expirationTime = BigInt.parse("9223372036854775807");
- Line 112: int -> BigInt
- Line 114-116: Change "set" function as below.
  set expirationTime(BigInt value) {
  _expirationTime = value;
  }

Comment: yes its sense to me , but this class is from huawei and  l can't change or update